# QGIS Cloud (Free) storage won't decrease

Tags: qgis-cloud

I reached my 50MB limit in free QGIS Cloud. After deleting a few unneeded map projects the storage warning stayed the same 50MB and disallows new uploads. Is that normal storage behavior, that the Free user cannot manage his storage amount under the limit?

Answer (score 1):

Please just delete single or all tables from the QGIS Cloud DB using the QGIS Browser or the QGIS DB Manager.